# Java multiplayer server blocking io

Tags: java

I am currently developing a prototype for a game and I need a simple server to run it.
At this stage, I don't want to invest the time learning about all the different full-featured multiplayer game servers already there (smartfox, etc...)

I know how to develop a basic Server with Threads listening on Sockets but I have ran into a roadblock. Here's the run() function of the Thread

```
public void run() {
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(mSocket1.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( mSocket1.getInputStream() ) );
            String inputLine1 = null, outputLine;

            out.println("hello");
            out.flush();

            while( (inputLine1 = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outputLine = mGameControl.processInput(mPlayerNum, inputLine1);
                out.println(outputLine);
                out.flush();
                if(outputLine.contentEquals("bye"))
                    break;
            }

            Terminate();
        }
        catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

Now my problem is that the thread is blocked waiting for input. I do have other similar Threads connected to other client which may result in information being dispatched to all clients...

How can I modify it so that a different Thread can interact with it and push info to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a synchronised public method which writes to your `PrintWriter`, and allow other threads to use it to send messages to your client. Call the same method from your read loop to avoid two threads writing at the same time.

Here's a tested example:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class SocketTest {
    public static class Client implements Runnable {

        private final BufferedReader in;
        private final PrintWriter out;

        public Client(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( clientSocket.getInputStream() ) );
        }

        public void run() {
            send("Hello");
            String inputLine1 = null, outputLine;
            try {
                while( (inputLine1 = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    outputLine = inputLine1.toLowerCase();
                    System.out.println(inputLine1);
                    send(outputLine);
                    if(outputLine.contentEquals("bye"))
                        break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public synchronized void send(String message) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(5050);
        Socket clientSocket = s.accept();
        Client client = new Client(clientSocket);
        Thread clientThread = new Thread(client);
        clientThread.start();
        int i = 1;
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            client.send("Tick " + (i++));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It won't work since `inputLine1 = in.readLine()` is blocking and will prevent any call made to the Thread instance functions from being executed until a line is read (at least that what happened when I tried)

Comment: What exactly did you try, and what exactly happened?

Comment: I did exactly what you've posted (minus the synchronized for testing purposes). But when the while loop in`run()` is waiting for `readLine()`, no call to writeMessage gets through until a line is read from `in`. That is, it looks like the call to writeMessage gets queued until the blocking i/o of `readLine()` returns

Comment: While `readLine` blocks the thread that's reading, it doesn't block operations on the socket by other threads. I've put a tested example in my answer -- let me know what the difference was...

Comment: I must have done something wrong when I tried it. Tested again (following your source) and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) to handle your connections and query treatments. Since I discovered that project, I never touched sockets directly anymore (except when writing C programs, etc.)

There are actually some [examples](http://www.jboss.org/netty/documentation.html#examples) to look at and the documentation is quite extensive. The project is very well alive since a couple of years already, and is not soon to die! There's a fairly large user base behind it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to perform a non-blocking read on the socket, one of the simplests ways is to use `available()`. Call available and if there is data to read (bytes pending > 0), perform the read, any way, wait using `Thread.sleep()` and try to read again. This allow the thread to do while waiting for input data and cat react to external signals.
The use of selectors is encouraged when you need to perform high-performance non-blocking read using one thread and several sockets (`java.nio.channels.Selector`).